# Have you applied Game Theory on a project?

Tags: game-theory

I haven't studied [game theory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Game_theory), but it fascinates me. My intuition is that it isn't used by most "enterprise app" developers. However, it is clearly relevant to the large online sites (e.g. recommendation systems), and a huge influence on SO.

Have you applied any principles of game theory in your daily projects? If so, which principles?

Comment: Um, can you explain how it's relevant to recommendation systems? I studied game theory in the context of economics in particular, and I can't figure out how the things I've studied might be applied to computer science. Granted, I only really remember stuff about Nash equilibrium, maybe other stuff that I don't remember applies more.

Answer (score 2):

I am pretty sure that [Hal Varian](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hal_Varian)'s work on auctions at Google must have a strong flavor of game theory, or at least micro-economics of decisions under uncertainty...

Answer (score 1):

I designed & wrote a review system and recommendation system for an online recipe-sharing website a long time ago. The recommendation system didn't require any game theory, just stats and sets, but thinking about the problems I had to solve with the reviews, they were definitely game-theory-y (though I didn't think about it that way at the time).

The problem that the site I worked on faced was that people could be both authors and reviewers, so there was a certain pressure to "pump up" their own recipes' stats perhaps by "pushing down" others. So there was a balance that had to grow organically from our rules to offset that selfish impulse; we did this with a per-user reputation score based on other peoples' reviews of their recipes and how helpful other people thought their reviews were. In retrospect I wish I had more rigorously applied some game theory here.

A research paper which discusses the same. 
Manipulation-Resistant Recommender Systems through Influence Limits, Resnick and Sami, 2008. [Here.](http://www.sigecom.org/exchanges/volume_7/3/RESNICK.pdf)

Comment: Jeff Atwood has made blog posts in the past about tweaking the SO reputation system. I don't remember how much detail he got into, but it was along similar lines.